# How to find out what the " recent activity" is on a question if it doesn't show up in dates?

Tags: support

I noticed an [old question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13947/12102) of mine had recent activity. It showed up near the top of the list of questions (when I was viewing while logged out). But when I looked at the question, I couldn't figure out what the activity was. All the answers, comments, and "edited by"'s seem old, but something was done "10 hours ago" (see screen shots below).

I welcome editing, just curious sometimes what it is!

For reference, right now the time is:

> [image]
>   [image] 
>   [image]

**UPDATE:** aha! now I see - [Community](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is a bot(!)(?)

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using every trick I know how, all I can tell is that Community seems to have bumped it for some reason. My guess is because it doesn't have an answer, Community is randomly bumping some old questions? Possibly because it has an answer, but no upvotes, or possibly for some other reason, but it seems likely Community is behind it, meaning it's some algorithm that decided to bump it.

Comment: That has been my observation as well.

Comment: I see! It seems [Community](http://space.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is of type `user`, and claims to be a bot. OK thanks! (I've added an update to my question)

Comment: Community is a bot, it's used by the SE staff as a kind of dumping ground for actions that are taken without a specified user. Moderators see it all the time, as it auto flags certain posts that meet certain criteria, there are other instances it shows up as well, however.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto thanks I'm figuring that out. Usually I think of "bots" as (roughly speaking) autonomous or algorithmic. You set up the rules, they implement predictably. Is that what you mean by "*actions that are taken without a specified user*" - OR - does it *also* include a way to anonymize actions taken by one or more moderators?

Comment: Overall I think it's just great! I'm just curious if the bot can be remote controlled :)

Comment: Not really. I think there's a way to make it delete spammy posts for us, but it's kind of annoying to do that... It will take on some users actions if that user goes away. I'm sure if you search MSE you can find a list of what community does.